# LINQ equivalent for SQL

Tags: c#, linq, ado.net, ado.net-entity-data-model

I am trying to convert a ASP.NET project to Entity framework. How to re-write the following query to its LINQ equivalent?

```
SELECT {Table1 objects}
FROM [Table1] tb1
INNER JOIN [Table2] tb2
ON tb1.Table1ID = tb2.fk_Table1ID
WHERE tb2.fk_attrib1 = '123' AND tb2.fk_attrb2 = '345'
ORDER BY tb1.attrib1
```

The result is a collection of `Table1` objects.
Here `Table1` and `Table2` correspond to object `System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet` of ADO.NET Entity Framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var results = from tb1 in Context.Table1
                join tb2 in Context.Table2 on tb1.Table1ID == tb2.fk_Table1ID
                where tb2.fk_attrib1 == "123" && tb2.fk_attrb2 == "345"
                orderby tb1.attrib1
                select tb1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
context.Table1
    .Where( o => o.Table2s.Any( o2 =>
        o2.fk_attrib1 == '123' &&
        o2.fk_attrib2 == '345' ) )
    .OrderBy( o => o.attrib1 )
    .ToList();
```

BTW, [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net) is great for trying out L2E queries.

Comment: don't see a InnerJoin link in this.

Comment: It does a join for you - try in LINQPad to see the generated SQL. Specifying a join in L2E is usually a code smell.

Answer (score 1):

This should help you a little bit. I suppose the main problem is with `JOIN` clause - in `EF` you can use `NavigationProperties` and don't need to worry about joining tables - `EF` will take care of that for you.

Also you are trying to filter on column from joined table. This you can do using `Any` method to find all `Table1` elements that are connected to `Table2` where those referenced elements have certain properties/columns. You should also get familiar with `All` method, as it might be useful to you in future.

```
from t1 in context.Table1
where t1.Table2s.Any(t2.fk_attrib1 == "123" && t2 => t2.fk_attrb2 == "345")
order by t1.attrib1
select t1;
```

Edit:
I assume that there is `1:n` relationship between `Table1` and `Table2` which results in enumerable collection as `NavigationProperty` in `Table1` objects.

Edit2:
Fixed error in code - didn't noticed that both attributes are from `Table2` not `Table1`

Comment: Besides the other queries do the job, this is the most elegant design.

Answer (score 0):

**Should** be something like this:

```
var result = (from tb1  in Table1
                from tb2 in Table2
                      where tb1.Key == tb2.Key && 
                                 tb2.fk_attrib1 = '123' && 
                                   tb2.fk_attrb2 = '345'
            select ione).OrderBy(p=>p.attrib1);
```

Hope this helps.